# Angular 7 on change hot deployment compile loop

Tags: angular, loops, angular7

Angular 7 app keeps recompiling whenever I make any change in any file. All packages are upto date.

```
Date: 2018-11-17T03:45:41.219Z - Hash: e021c3ac346efa4892da - Time: 2200ms
6 unchanged chunks
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2018-11-17T03:45:41.729Z - Hash: e021c3ac346efa4892da - Time: 292ms
6 unchanged chunks
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2018-11-17T03:45:42.412Z - Hash: e021c3ac346efa4892da - Time: 275ms
6 unchanged chunks
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2018-11-17T03:45:45.831Z - Hash: e021c3ac346efa4892da - Time: 409ms
6 unchanged chunks
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: that's the way its supposed to work...

Comment: But UI page is also keep getting refreshed because this keep going on forever and I have to kill it and start again using npm start

Comment: Looks like you've implemented Lazy Loading and there an issue with your Route Config.

Comment: I recently added one new route with parameter. And is there any way to disable lazy loading.

Comment: If you set it up to be lazy loaded, that is how it will always function.  If you don't, then it won't.  See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: This was resolved. Issue was because codebase was on a network device. After moving to local drive issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved. Issue was because codebase was on a network device. After moving to local drive issue resolved